# What is the shortest way to drop partial duplicates from a list of tuple in Python without using Pandas?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a list of tuples where each tuple is structured like this : `(Name, Age, City)`. I have, at most, about 30 tuples in my list.

There are no duplicates. However, sometimes, *Name* and *Age* are duplicated.

**Example input would be something like this :**

```
lst = [("Dave", 20, "Dublin"), ("Dave", 20, "Paris"), ("Lisa", 20, "Monaco"), ("Lisa", 20, "London"), ("Frank", 56, "Berlin"),  ("Frank", 40, "Berlin")]
```

I would like to remove *partial* duplicates, where the subset would be *Name* and *Age* but not *City*. Ideally I'd like to keep the first duplicate. I guess an example would make it easier to understand :

**Expected output :**

```
expected_lst = [(Dave, 20, Dublin), (Lisa, 20, Monaco), (Frank, 56, Berlin),  (Frank, 40, Berlin)]
```

Dave's and Lisa's duplicates were removed, but not Frank since the *Age* does not match.

**What I have tried so far :**

I checked these posts :

- [Python remove partial duplicates from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779544/python-remove-partial-duplicates-from-a-list)
- [Removing elements that have consecutive partial duplicates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380270/removing-elements-that-have-consecutive-partial-duplicates-in-python)
- [Efficiently remove partial duplicates in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122700/efficiently-remove-partial-duplicates-in-a-list-of-tuples)

But they do not seem to match what I'm asking for and I didn't manage to understand how to apply the solutions to my case.

I did find a solution that seems to work, which is to convert my list to a pandas DataFrame and then drop duplicates using the `drop_duplicates()` function and its `subset` parameter :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns= ["Name", "Age", "City"]).drop_duplicates(subset=(["Name", "Age"]))
```

And then using itertuples to convert it back to a list.

```
expected_lst = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

However, I do not need pandas for any of the other steps of my code. Changing the type of my data seems a bit "much".

**I was therefore wondering if there was a better way to get my expected output, that would maybe either be quicker or shorter to write ? I'm not an expert but I assume that converting a list to a pandas DataFrame and then back to a list is not very efficient ?**

Comment: How long are your lists? Pandas is implemented in C and can loop through long lists much faster than Python. But, for small lists the overheads aren't worth it.

Comment: @MatBailie my list is about 10 to 30 tuples long, and each tuple has 3 elements.

Comment: Would need to reverse the list first, so the first tuple takes precedence: https://trinket.io/python/ea3376af6e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tuple of the "unique" elements (name, age) as dict key, where the value is the full tuple. Thus the name+age is unique.

In order to ensure you keep the first entry, you need to check if (name, age) is in temp before inserting it. edit: or just reverse the list, like MatBailie said

```
data = [("Dave", 20, "Dublin"), ("Dave", 20, "Paris"), ("Lisa", 20, "Monaco"), ("Lisa", 20, "London"), ("Frank", 56, "Berlin"),  ("Frank", 40, "Berlin")]

temp = {(name, age) : (name, age, city) for name, age, city in reversed(data)}
for unique_item in temp.values():
    print(unique_item)
```

> ('Dave', 40, 'Paris')
> ('Lisa', 20, 'London')
> ('Frank', 56, 'Berlin')
> ('Frank', 40, 'Berlin')

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! Does that mean that, by default, Python browses a dictionnary in the reversed order ? For my specific case the order did not matter as much but thank you anyway as this might be useful for other people as well.

Comment: Whenever you have a duplicate, that means the dictionary key is the same, therefore you will overwrite the previous duplicate value. By going in reverse, you just overwrite the later values with the earliest. My original implementation was to check for a duplicate and discard the later duplicates, rather than saving them.

Comment: Oh my bad I was confused and thought this had to do with the order of my values, now I understand what you mean, reversing the list ensures that I only keep the first duplicate. Thank you this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `itertools.groupby`, using the first 2 elements of your tuples as a key (you first need to sort the data, since `groupby` operates on consecutive entries):

```
from itertools import groupby
filtered_data = [next(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda tup: tup[:2])]

# [('Dave', 20, 'Dublin'), ('Frank', 40, 'Berlin'), ('Frank', 56, 'Berlin'), ('Lisa', 20, 'London')]
```

Of course, this only works if the initial order of tuples doesn't matter to you. Otherwise, @KennyOstrom's answer preserves the original order.

Comment: Thank you so much, it also worked ! Since the order of tuples does not matter to me this is also a very good solution. I had never used itertools.groupby before so I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: You're welcome; and I'd advise you to study the whole (it's of modest size) `itertools` module, it's very nice.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted Kenny's answer as it was a little shorter and I thought it could be useful for people who might need to keep the order but your answer was also really helpful and I'll definitely check the itertools module as it is not the first time I answer one of my questions with this library :)